# Derive base class function with/without arguments

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overloading, overriding

What is the issue with below code?

```
  class B
{
public:
    int test()
    {
        cout<<"B:test()"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int test(int i)
    {
        cout<<"B test(int i)"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

class D: public B
{
public:

    int test(char x) { cout<<"D test"<<endl; return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to do that in real code?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is *name hiding*. Function `test()` in the derived class `D` *hides* the overloads of `test()` in the base class `B`, so those won't be considered by overload resolution in the expression:

```
d.test()
```

Just add a `using` declaration:

```
class D: public B
{
public:
    using B::test;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    int test(char x) { cout<<"D test"<<endl;}
};
```

Also notice, that your overloads of `test()` in the base class `B` are supposed to return an `int`, but they return nothing.

Per paragraph 6.6.3/2 of the C++11 Standard, falling off the end of a value-returning function without returning anything is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: 'B::test' : must return a value

Comment: @PowerPC: Oh, correct! I missed that, thank you. Going to edit

Answer (score 3):

[This is a textbook case of hiding](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
d.test();
```

will not work since your derived class `test(char)` hides all base class functions, there will be no matching function to call if you do the above.